# Mapping request params/ path variable to Dto in GET request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'd like to create a controller which will return Page object. I will need page `Pageable` to have with page number and its size (it cannot be larger than 50) and some variables which will be search criteria. If this was a POST request, it could look as follows:

`public Page<SomeDto) getDto(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDto requestDto, Page pageRequest)`

However, it is a GET request so `@RequestBody` cannot/shouldn't be used.
Additionally, I would like to have something akin to @Valid so that Spring will automatically reject bad request.

I'm wondering whether:

1. it is possible to and if so how to implement this and have already created Dto from values taken from URL (@PathVariable or @RequestParam) as if it was POST request which maps body to object.

I'd like to avoid using some kind of that code:

`public String updateFoos(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {}`

2. if what is described in 1st is not possible, what solution would be closest as to meeting those requirements?

Comment: Please clarify "However, it is a POST request so @RequestBody cannot be used." Do you mean GET ?

Comment: @tobhai Yes. I will change my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a HTTP body (and therefore a `@RequestBody`) for every HTTP requests no matter what HTTP method is used. However, it is not a good REST API design to use a HTTP body for GET request (cf. https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html)

You can do bean validation with @PathVariable or @RequestParam arguments, you just have to put the annotation you want next to these annotations

Answer (score 0):

For request param in GET method, just create a class and declare fields that has same name as the param. Then use the class as request param.
Spring will automatically map the url param to the fields.

For example:

```java
@Data
class RequestDTO{
    private Long userId;
    private Long customName;
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public void testRequest(RequestDTO request){

}
```

and when you send a url like `/test?userId=1&customName=Mike`, the params will be mapped to `RequestDTO`